# How to setup Braintree API in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, braintree

I want use braintree for website paymentgateway, unfortunately when I follow the guideline online, & the code unable to be use in node js. Is anything missing?

Index.js:

```
//send token to clients

app.get("/client_token", function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  });
});

//Receive payment from clients

app.post("/checkout", function (req, res) {
  var nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
  // Use payment method nonce here
});

//Test sandbox
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {

  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  if (result.success) {
    console.log('Transaction ID: ' + result.transaction.id);
  } else {
    console.error(result.message);
  }
});
```

Error unable pass the node js npm start:

**paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,**

Details in IDE:

ReferenceError: nonceFromTheClient is not defined

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/desmondkam/codecampvn/index.js:37:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at startup (node.js:160:18)
at node.js:445:3
```

---

#### Solved

## Remove //Test sandbox part would solve the problem of compiled normal in localhost & IDE.

## Inorder to running with Sandbox, would required some add-on code regarding: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/node:

```
"fake-valid-nonce"
```

Your code would be:

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
  amount: "10.00",
  paymentMethodNonce: "fake-valid-nonce",
  options: {
    submitForSettlement: true
  }
}, function (err, result) {
});
```

Comment: You have defined  `nonceFromTheClient` in router, that's why you are getting undefined error in your sandbox

Comment: Alright, i got your point.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for a solution,

```
 import braintree, {
 BraintreeGateway,
 KeyGatewayConfig,
 ValidatedResponse,
 Transaction,
 ClientToken,
 TransactionRequest
} from 'braintree';

import { ITransactionResponse } from '../components/payment/payment.types';

export default class BraintreeWrapper {

private gateway: BraintreeGateway;

constructor() {
    // get the braintree key gateway config from environment, which we set in global environment objecr
    const env: KeyGatewayConfig = environment.braintree;

    // creates a gateway instance using 
    this.gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway(env);
}

// generate the client token
public async generateToken(): Promise < string > {
    const result : ValidatedResponse < ClientToken > = await this.gateway.clientToken.generate({});
    const { clientToken } = result;
    return clientToken;
}

// make transaction
public async transaction(request: TransactionRequest): Promise < ITransactionResponse > {
        const result: ValidatedResponse < Transaction > = await this.gateway.transaction.sale(request);

        // extract transaction response keys from result
        const { 
            transaction: {
                id,
                status,
                type,
                currencyIsoCode,
                amount,
                merchantAccountId,
                orderId,
                createdAt,
                updatedAt,
            } 
        } = result;

        // map transaction response keys
        const response: ITransactionResponse = {
            id,
            status,
            type,
            currencyIsoCode,
            amount,
            merchantAccountId,
            orderId,
            createdAt,
            updatedAt,
        };

        return response;
}


}
```

I have created a guide to help you get started with the implementation

[Integrate Braintree Payment Gateway SDK in Node.js and React](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/integration-of-the-braintree-payment-gateway-sdk-in-node-js-and-react-js-ba64bd48177f)